# Symfony API POST : binding request with FormType not working

Tags: php, symfony

I am new with Symfony and I have problems figure it out why my code is not working.

In my controller, I have a function managing Post request of my API:

```
public function postMyEventAction(Request $request)
    {
        

        $entity = new MyEvent();
        
        $form = $this->createForm(new MyEventType(), $entity);
        
        $form->bind($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();
```

....
My FormType

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class MyEventType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('organiser')
            ->add('token')
            ->add('event')
            ->add('persons')
        ;
    }
    
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'EventManageBundle\Entity\MyEvent',
            'csrf_protection' => false
        ));
    }


}
```

When I calling my API with a JSON post request, `$entity` stays empty.
I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to set the data to the entity (I personally use a Form Handler to keep separate a logic) like:

```
$entity->setOrganizer($form->get('organizer')->getData());
```

and so on...

Comment: Thanks, it is a way to avoid the binding method. ;-)